# dynamically set iframe src

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a program which will dynamically set an iframe src to load pages. I need to hook a event handler for the page completely loaded. How can i do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 136, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function iframeDidLoad() {
    alert('Done');
}

function newSite() {
    var sites = ['http://getprismatic.com',
                 'http://gizmodo.com/',
                 'http://lifehacker.com/']

    document.getElementById('myIframe').src = sites[Math.floor(Math.random() * sites.length)];
}    
</script>
<input type="button" value="Change site" onClick="newSite()" />
<iframe id="myIframe" src="http://getprismatic.com/" onLoad="iframeDidLoad();"></iframe>
```

Example at http://jsfiddle.net/MALuP/

Comment: The link in this answer is broken now. It might be useful to re-upload this on http://www.jsfiddle.net, and then post a link to that.

Comment: Good idea. I just changed it.

Answer (score 30):

Try this:

```
top.document.getElementById('AppFrame').setAttribute("src",fullPath);
```

Comment: Works nicely! Working example wrapped in a link: <a onClick="top.document.getElementById('iframe_id').setAttribute('src','https://photosonthefly.com');" >Photos on the fly</a>

This method would require a CSS pointer, like <style>a:hover {cursor: pointer;}</style>

Answer (score 15):

Try this...

```
function urlChange(url) {
    var site = url+'?toolbar=0&amp;navpanes=0&amp;scrollbar=0';
    document.getElementById('iFrameName').src = site;
}

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="urlChange('www.mypdf.com/test.pdf')">TEST </a>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should also consider that in some Opera versions onload is fired several times and add some hooks:

```
// fixing Opera 9.26, 10.00
if (doc.readyState && doc.readyState != 'complete') {
    // Opera fires load event multiple times
    // Even when the DOM is not ready yet
    // this fix should not affect other browsers
    return;
}

// fixing Opera 9.64
if (doc.body && doc.body.innerHTML == "false") {
    // In Opera 9.64 event was fired second time
    // when body.innerHTML changed from false
    // to server response approx. after 1 sec
    return;
}
```

Code borrowed from [Ajax Upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)

Comment: Also, if you are using jQuery you can bind load event handler for iframe `$('iframe').load(function (){ ...do smth... })`

Answer (score 3):

try this code. then 'formId' div can set the image.

```
$('#formId').append('<iframe style="width: 100%;height: 500px" src="/document_path/name.jpg"' +
 'title="description"> </iframe> ');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
document.frames["myiframe"].onload = function(){
   alert("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: document.frames is not valid JavaScript. parent.frames might be an option though... but it does seem that the best way to access iframes in JavaScript is indeed with getElementById.