# Html code as IFRAME source rather than a URL

Tags: html, iframe, frame

This standard code for an IFRAME, is there a way to replace the src URL with Just html code? so my problem is simple, I have a page it loads an HTML body from MYSQL I want to present that code in a frame so it renders it self independent of the rest of the page and in the confines of that specific bordering.

```
<iframe src="http://example.com" name="test" height="120" width="600">You need a Frames Capable browser to view this content.</iframe>
```

Answer (score 233, accepted):

You can do this with a data URL.  This includes the entire document in a single string of HTML.  For example, the following HTML:

```
<html><body>foo</body></html>
```

can be encoded as this:

```
data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3Chtml%3E%3Cbody%3Efoo%3C/body%3E%3C/html%3E
```

and then set as the `src` attribute of the iframe.  [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TCnG4/).

---

Edit: The other alternative is to do this with Javascript.  This is almost certainly the technique I'd choose.  You can't guarantee how long a data URL the browser will accept.  The Javascript technique would look something like this:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('foo'),
    iframedoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

iframedoc.body.innerHTML = 'Hello world';
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TCnG4/1/)

---

**Edit 2 (December 2017)**: use the Html5's **srcdoc** attribute, just like in **Saurabh Chandra Patel**'s answer, who now should be the accepted answer! If you can [detect IE/Edge efficiently](https://codepen.io/gapcode/pen/vEJNZN), a tip is to use [srcdoc-polyfill](https://github.com/jugglinmike/srcdoc-polyfill) library only for them and the "pure" srcdoc attribute in all non-IE/Edge browsers (check [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-srcdoc) to be sure).

```
<iframe srcdoc="<html><body>Hello, <b>world</b>.</body></html>"></iframe>
```

Comment: The problem with the JS approach is that if the HTML contains single quotes (which the OP doesn't know until runtime), they will need to be escaped from a JS point of view in order not to break the innerHTML assignment statement...?

Comment: Yes, obviously the JS would need to be valid. This is why, contrary to what I said in my answer, I would almost certainly not do this. I'd just use a normal iframe!

Comment: Internet explorer support? Data URI can't represent html files in IE8

Comment: Is there a way to provide cross origin headers here? Chrome keeps complaining about `Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a cross-origin frame`.

Comment: @AndrewSwan I don't quite understand the problem with the single quotes. Can you give me an example?

Comment: For anyone like me who was looking how to encode HTML this way with php, you want rawurlencode (http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)

Comment: well you could try backticks in the script, it really helped me out a lot with escapes and stuff.

Comment: Note that if you use `innerHTML` browser will not execute descendant script tags. For more information check [Security considerations section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)  of Element.innerHTML MDN page.

Comment: @lonesomeday How you have encoded html to "%3Chtml%3E%3Cbody%3Efoo%3C/body%3E%3C/html%3E" by using jquery.parseHTML() or any vanilla javascript?

Comment: @rselvaganesh `"data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURI(html)`

Comment: why <iframe src="data:text/html;charset=utf-8,ABC#123"></iframe> down not work? https://jsfiddle.net/g57kync0/

Comment: @tumbudu Give it a whirl with `encodeURIComponent`, or give the better solution in my answer a go.

Answer (score 164):

use `html5`'s new attribute `srcdoc` (srcdoc-polyfill) [Docs](https://github.com/jugglinmike/srcdoc-polyfill)

```
<iframe 
    srcdoc="<html>
              <body>Hello, <b>world</b>.</body>
           </html>">
</iframe>
```

Browser support  - Tested in the following browsers:

```
Microsoft Internet Explorer
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
Microsoft Edge
13, 14
Safari
4, 5.0, 5.1 ,6, 6.2, 7.1, 8, 9.1, 10
Google Chrome
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24.0.1312.5 (beta), 25.0.1364.5 (dev), 55
Opera
11.1, 11.5, 11.6, 12.10, 12.11 (beta) , 42
Mozilla FireFox
3.0, 3.6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 (beta), 50
```

If your HTML [contains double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102636/html-code-as-iframe-source-rather-than-a-url#comment102845856_30273995), consider [escaping its double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015345/how-do-i-properly-escape-quotes-inside-html-attributes)

```
<iframe 
    srcdoc="<html>
              <body>&quot;Hello&quot;</body>
           </html>">
</iframe>
```

...or [use Javascript to set the `srcdoc` attribute dynamically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/srcdoc#examples)

```
iframe.srcdoc = '<html>
                  <body>"Hello"</body>
               </html>';
```

Remember [wait for the iframe's `onload` event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000987/dynamically-set-iframe-src)  before trying to use Javascript to manipulate the iframe's content (before adding event listeners, etc)

Comment: Thanks ! I needed a solution for a modern webkit webview, and that was by far the simplest way to do it!

Comment: It is not supported in IE

Comment: official doc say its supported from IE-6 +

Comment: CanIUse.com says that the support is pretty poor: http://caniuse.com/#search=srcdoc

Comment: @msquitieri No, it says *native* support poor, not the polyfill's.

Comment: But this breaks as soon as you start using quotation marks

Comment: Not supported in IE or Edge: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_srcdoc.asp

Comment: Tested working in Chromium 81 on 6 May 2020. Using `srcdoc` brings the advantage you can style the background via the parent frame for continuity without using javascript or css. If formatting attribute values from textfiles with bash(1) use recode(1) with the `ascii..html` option.

Answer (score 24):

According to W3Schools, HTML 5 lets you do this using a [new "srcdoc" attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_srcdoc.asp), but the browser support seems very limited.

Comment: There is also [a Polyfill for srcdoc](https://github.com/jugglinmike/srcdoc-polyfill).

Comment: @UweKeim Thanks for suggesting the polyfill. It's lightweight and works great.

Comment: According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-srcdoc) only infamous Microsoft's IE and Edge browsers (besides Opera Mini) don't support the **srcdoc** attribute, so it is NOT "very limited". Just use [srcdoc-polyfill](https://github.com/jugglinmike/srcdoc-polyfill) for Microsoft users.

Answer (score 4):

**iframe srcdoc:** This attribute contains **HTML** content, which will override **src** attribute. If a browser does not support the **srcdoc** attribute, it will fall back to the URL in the **src** attribute.

Let's understand it with an example

```
<iframe 
    name="my_iframe" 
    srcdoc="<h1 style='text-align:center; color:#9600fa'>Welcome to iframes</h1>"
    src="https://www.birthdaycalculatorbydate.com/"
    width="500px"
    height="200px"
></iframe>
```

Original content is taken from [iframes](https://www.iframeinhtml.com/).

Answer (score 4):

> I have a page it loads an HTML body from MYSQL I want to present that code in a frame so it renders it self independent of the rest of the page and in the confines of that specific bordering.

An [`object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) with a unencoded  dataUri might have also fit your need if it was only to load a portion of data text:

> The HTML `<object>` element represents an external resource, which can be treated as an image, a nested browsing context, or a resource to be handled by a plugin.

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bGKQVRr or snippet below

```css
body {display:flex;min-height:25em;}
p {margin:auto;}
object {margin:0 auto;background:lightgray;}
```

```html
<p>here My uploaded content: </p>
<object data='data:text/html,
  <style>

.table {
  display: table;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.table > * {
  display: table-row;
}

.table > main {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>


<div class="table">
  <header>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>subTitle</p>
  </header>

  <main>
    <p>Collection</p>
    <p>Version</p>
    <p>Id</p>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <p>Edition</p>
  </footer>'>

</object>
```

But keeping your Iframe idea, You could also load your HTML inside your iframe tag and set it  as the srcdoc value.You should not have to mind about quotes nor turning it into a dataUri but only mind to fire onload once.

> The HTML Inline Frame element (`<iframe>`) represents a nested browsing context, embedding another HTML page into the current one.

Both iframe below will render the same, one require extra javascript.

example loading a full document : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/JjZeYyg or snippet below

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 25em;
}

p {
  margin: auto;
}

iframe {
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  background:lightgray;
}
```

```html
<p>here my uploaded contents =>:</p>
  <iframe srcdoc='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style>
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
}

body.table {
  display: table;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
}

.table > * {
  display: table-row;
}

.table > main {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
</head>

<body class="table">
  <header>
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>injected via <code>srcdoc</code></p>
  </header>

  <main>
    <p>Collection</p>
    <p>Version</p>
    <p>Id</p>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <p>Edition</p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>'>

</iframe>

  <iframe onload="this.setAttribute('srcdoc', this.innerHTML);this.setAttribute('onload','')">
    <!-- below html loaded -->
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <style>
        html,
        body {
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          overflow:auto;
        }
        
        body.table {
          display: table;
          text-align: center;
          width: 100%;
        }
        
        .table>* {
          display: table-row;
        }
        
        .table>main {
          display: table-cell;
          height: 100%;
          vertical-align: middle;
        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body class="table">
      <header>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Injected from <code>innerHTML</code></p>
      </header>

      <main>
        <p>Collection</p>
        <p>Version</p>
        <p>Id</p>
      </main>

      <footer>
        <p>Edition</p>
      </footer>
    </body>

    </html>
    </iframe>
```

Comment: Could you please show your code example in a codepen? its not working for me, nothing is rendered in the iframe using your 2nd example, thx

Comment: @OJB1 here is the codepen with the iframes : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/JjZeYyg & the object https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bGKQVRr