# php encoding html content for machine reading

Tags: php, html, iframe, encoding

Hi I need to encode something like this ,

```
< html>< body>foo< /body>< /html>
```

into something like this

```
data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3Chtml%3E%3Cbody%3Efoo%3C/body%3E%3C/html%3E
```

I am not sure how to explain this but I need it for doing something like this.
[Html code as IFRAME source rather than a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102636/html-code-as-iframe-source-rather-than-a-url?lq=1)

and I need a `php` function to do so.
Thanks in advance .

Comment: `rawurlencode`. Also, you can indent code with four spaces to make it render like this: `<html><body>`, and then you won't need the extra spaces to keep the tags visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at : [rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) it encodes the given string according to » RFC 3986.