# Add contents to an empty frame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an empty frame in my page, with `src` set to '' (empty).
I also have a string like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base src="http://www.example.com">
    <title>Blah</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Fancy web page</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to populate the iframe with the string, so that the *exact* content of it matches the string.

What's the best way to do this? I am going insane trying to do it.

Comment: Probably this can help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102636/html-code-as-iframe-source-rather-than-a-url

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an id on the iframe and then set the innerHTML of the iframe's document body and head to the head/body string values.

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/theoutlander/dw3r7/1/

```
<iframe id=testframe></iframe>

var strHead = '<base src="http://www.example.com"><title>Blah</title>'
var strBody = '<p>Fancy web page</p>';

testframe.document.head.innerHTML = strHead;
testframe.document.body.innerHTML = strBody;
```

Comment: My input doesn't come in two pieces. Plus, body might well have attributes which would be lost. The point of my question is that I have a whole string that represents the whole page...

Comment: Hmm. I guess my solutions are hacky for what you want. What about posting the string to a server instead? You could serve it as a resource in that case and have the iframe point to that location? I need to ask what you're trying to do here? Why do you have a page as a string?