# Setting iframe window.location causing crash on Android 4.3 native browser (Chromium/WebKit)

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, webkit, android-webview

I have some javascript which sets the `window.location` of an `iframe` to load another html page. For some reason this causes both the WebView and the native Android browser (Chromium) to crash in Android 4.3 and earlier. On Android 4.4 there are no issues. It is my understanding that on 4.3 and earlier Chromium is using the Webkit engine, and starting on 4.4 it is using a Chrome based engine.

Is this a known WebKit/Chromium issue? Are there any work arounds?

For what its worth, below are the log messages generated by CatLog when I replicate the issue in an emulator. Unfortunately, I don't think there is much to glean from it.

```
07-02 18:24:32.523: D/dalvikvm(750): GC_CONCURRENT freed 449K, 21% free 2467K/3092K, paused 15ms+2ms, total 910ms
07-02 18:24:32.613: W/ActivityManager(281): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@416c4788
07-02 18:24:39.824: E/ThrottleService(281): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-02 18:25:00.503: A/libc(1147): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x000002d8 (code=1), thread 1167 (WebViewCoreThre)
07-02 18:25:00.603: I/DEBUG(35): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
07-02 18:25:00.603: I/DEBUG(35): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:4.2.2/JB_MR1.1/576024:eng/test-keys'
07-02 18:25:00.603: I/DEBUG(35): Revision: '0'
07-02 18:25:00.613: I/DEBUG(35): pid: 1147, tid: 1167, name: UNKNOWN  >>> com.android.browser <<<
07-02 18:25:00.613: I/DEBUG(35): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 000002d8
07-02 18:25:00.843: I/DEBUG(35):     r0 00000000  r1 56029299  r2 000000aa  r3 00000000
07-02 18:25:00.843: I/DEBUG(35):     r4 00000000  r5 4971d898  r6 2afe66e0  r7 50ea2d11
07-02 18:25:00.843: I/DEBUG(35):     r8 00000000  r9 2e808091  sl 4835d6e3  fp 4971d8f0
07-02 18:25:00.843: I/DEBUG(35):     ip 48855084  sp 4971d800  lr 4835d6ff  pc 4827f13e  cpsr 80000030
07-02 18:25:00.843: I/DEBUG(35):     d0  bf80000053b44e7c  d1  bf800000bf800000
07-02 18:25:00.843: I/DEBUG(35):     d2  bf800000bf800000  d3  bf800000bf800000
07-02 18:25:00.843: I/DEBUG(35):     d4  3fc17c0000000000  d5  411dc5e400000000
07-02 18:25:00.843: I/DEBUG(35):     d6  0001860100000000  d7  40f8601000000000
07-02 18:25:00.843: I/DEBUG(35):     d8  41d4ed139f1e1feb  d9  41d4ed139f21531e
07-02 18:25:00.843: I/DEBUG(35):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
07-02 18:25:00.843: I/DEBUG(35):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
07-02 18:25:00.843: I/DEBUG(35):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
07-02 18:25:00.843: I/DEBUG(35):     scr 60000013
07-02 18:25:00.853: I/DEBUG(35): backtrace:
07-02 18:25:00.853: I/DEBUG(35):     #00  pc 0015113e  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-02 18:25:00.853: I/DEBUG(35):     #01  pc 0022f6fb  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-02 18:25:00.853: I/DEBUG(35):     #02  pc 0045a7a5  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-02 18:25:00.853: I/DEBUG(35):     #03  pc 00000098  <unknown>
07-02 18:25:00.853: I/DEBUG(35): stack:
07-02 18:25:00.853: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d7c0  2a6f7c40  [heap]
07-02 18:25:00.864: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d7c4  50ea2d11  
07-02 18:25:00.864: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d7c8  00000000  
07-02 18:25:00.864: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d7cc  4857ace5  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-02 18:25:00.864: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d7d0  2a73c084  [heap]
07-02 18:25:00.864: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d7d4  4857cf7b  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-02 18:25:00.864: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d7d8  2a118e10  [heap]
07-02 18:25:00.864: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d7dc  00000004  
07-02 18:25:00.864: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d7e0  2a73c080  [heap]
07-02 18:25:00.864: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d7e4  4971d898  
07-02 18:25:00.864: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d7e8  2b077a58  [heap]
07-02 18:25:00.864: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d7ec  2ae5c2e0  [heap]
07-02 18:25:00.873: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d7f0  2afe66e0  [heap]
07-02 18:25:00.873: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d7f4  4835b687  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-02 18:25:00.873: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d7f8  df0027ad  
07-02 18:25:00.873: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d7fc  00000000  
07-02 18:25:00.873: I/DEBUG(35):     #00  4971d800  00000000  
07-02 18:25:00.873: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d804  4971d898  
07-02 18:25:00.873: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d808  2afe66e0  [heap]
07-02 18:25:00.873: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d80c  4835d6ff  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-02 18:25:00.873: I/DEBUG(35):     #01  4971d810  4971d8e4  
07-02 18:25:00.883: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d814  4971d8a4  
07-02 18:25:00.883: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d818  4971d8e4  
07-02 18:25:00.883: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d81c  4971d8e0  
07-02 18:25:00.883: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d820  4971d8a4  
07-02 18:25:00.883: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d824  4971d8e4  
07-02 18:25:00.883: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d828  4971d8e0  
07-02 18:25:00.883: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d82c  2a73c08c  [heap]
07-02 18:25:00.883: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d830  00000000  
07-02 18:25:00.883: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d834  4866acdb  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-02 18:25:00.883: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d838  4971d848  
07-02 18:25:00.883: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d83c  4971d8e0  
07-02 18:25:00.883: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d840  2a118e68  [heap]
07-02 18:25:00.893: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d844  00000003  
07-02 18:25:00.893: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d848  4971d904  
07-02 18:25:00.893: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d84c  48587259  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-02 18:25:00.893: I/DEBUG(35):          ........  ........
07-02 18:25:00.893: I/DEBUG(35):     #02  4971d878  00000004  
07-02 18:25:00.893: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d87c  4971d904  
07-02 18:25:00.893: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d880  4971d8f8  
07-02 18:25:00.903: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d884  4866adb1  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-02 18:25:00.903: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d888  4971d8e0  
07-02 18:25:00.903: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d88c  2a118e10  [heap]
07-02 18:25:00.903: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d890  2a73c07c  [heap]
07-02 18:25:00.903: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d894  2a73d048  [heap]
07-02 18:25:00.903: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d898  4971d8bc  
07-02 18:25:00.903: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d89c  4971d900  
07-02 18:25:00.903: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d8a0  00000002  
07-02 18:25:00.913: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d8a4  48853000  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-02 18:25:00.913: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d8a8  48846a10  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-02 18:25:00.913: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d8ac  2a118e10  [heap]
07-02 18:25:00.913: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d8b0  00000000  
07-02 18:25:00.913: I/DEBUG(35):          4971d8b4  33c181f1  
07-02 18:25:00.913: I/DEBUG(35):          ........  ........
07-02 18:25:00.913: I/DEBUG(35): memory near r1:
07-02 18:25:00.913: I/DEBUG(35):     56029278 2b4012e8 2e808091 3374f201 50e08081  
07-02 18:25:00.923: I/DEBUG(35):     56029288 50e08081 48856b7c 4b56eca0 3373c581  
07-02 18:25:00.923: I/DEBUG(35):     56029298 4d622585 50e08081 48856e8c 2ae5c2e0  
07-02 18:25:00.923: I/DEBUG(35):     560292a8 4d622599 2e808091 3374a521 50e08081  
07-02 18:25:00.923: I/DEBUG(35):     560292b8 50e08081 2e808091 2e808091 2e808091  
07-02 18:25:00.923: I/DEBUG(35):     560292c8 33724501 4d672d69 50e08081 48856d9c  
07-02 18:25:00.923: I/DEBUG(35):     560292d8 2b357d50 4d6225a9 337408e1 50e08081  
07-02 18:25:00.923: I/DEBUG(35):     560292e8 50e08081 2e808091 2e808091 337408e1  
07-02 18:25:00.923: I/DEBUG(35):     560292f8 50e08081 50e08081 48856ebc 2a97f9b8  
07-02 18:25:00.923: I/DEBUG(35):     56029308 3373a801 50e08081 50e08081 2e808091  
07-02 18:25:00.933: I/DEBUG(35):     56029318 2e808091 33708121 00000028 50e08081  
07-02 18:25:00.933: I/DEBUG(35):     56029328 48856bdc 2ab7cb30 337391a1 50e08081  
07-02 18:25:00.933: I/DEBUG(35):     56029338 50e08081 2e808091 2e808091 2e808091  
07-02 18:25:00.933: I/DEBUG(35):     56029348 33708121 00000030 50e08081 4885f234  
07-02 18:25:00.933: I/DEBUG(35):     56029358 4bdaee90 2e808091 337393e1 50e08081  
07-02 18:25:00.933: I/DEBUG(35):     56029368 50e08081 2e808091 2e808091 33708121  
07-02 18:25:00.933: I/DEBUG(35): memory near r5:
07-02 18:25:00.933: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d878 00000004 4971d904 4971d8f8 4866adb1  
07-02 18:25:00.933: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d888 4971d8e0 2a118e10 2a73c07c 2a73d048  
07-02 18:25:00.933: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d898 4971d8bc 4971d900 00000002 48853000  
07-02 18:25:00.944: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d8a8 48846a10 2a118e10 00000000 33c181f1  
07-02 18:25:00.944: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d8b8 560c9d25 2e808091 00000004 485886ad  
07-02 18:25:00.944: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d8c8 4971d904 00000002 5603bb59 3379c381  
07-02 18:25:00.944: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d8d8 2a119228 4a10a09c 4a10a09c 3b282851  
07-02 18:25:00.944: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d8e8 4a10a001 4971d8e4 4971d910 3f885e38  
07-02 18:25:00.944: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d8f8 560c9d25 50e1e105 303b4ad1 3b282851  
07-02 18:25:00.944: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d908 5602340d 5603bb59 4971d930 3f896c84  
07-02 18:25:00.944: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d918 50e1e105 303b4ad1 3b282851 4d626ab5  
07-02 18:25:00.954: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d928 56023455 5603bb59 4971d94c 3f887360  
07-02 18:25:00.954: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d938 3b282851 4d626ab5 303b29f1 560233e9  
07-02 18:25:00.954: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d948 303b3b5d 4971d964 5148dc38 303b0409  
07-02 18:25:00.954: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d958 3b282851 3030a8e1 303267f9 4971d984  
07-02 18:25:00.954: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d968 2722d674 303b0409 3b282851 3030a8e1  
07-02 18:25:00.954: I/DEBUG(35): memory near r6:
07-02 18:25:00.954: I/DEBUG(35):     2afe66c0 4882b908 00000001 00000013 2b2ae6e8  
07-02 18:25:00.954: I/DEBUG(35):     2afe66d0 2afe66a0 00000023 00000020 00000103  
07-02 18:25:00.954: I/DEBUG(35):     2afe66e0 48804638 0000000a 2afac848 4c33bd68  
07-02 18:25:00.964: I/DEBUG(35):     2afe66f0 2b2b7823 00000005 00000008 00000008  
07-02 18:25:00.964: I/DEBUG(35):     2afe6700 00000008 00000025 0000002a 0000004e  
07-02 18:25:00.964: I/DEBUG(35):     2afe6710 00000052 000000a0 000000a0 00000000  
07-02 18:25:00.964: I/DEBUG(35):     2afe6720 2a7445f8 00000000 00000000 00000000  
07-02 18:25:00.964: I/DEBUG(35):     2afe6730 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
07-02 18:25:00.964: I/DEBUG(35):     2afe6740 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
07-02 18:25:00.964: I/DEBUG(35):     2afe6750 2afd78b8 4c826478 00000000 2a19ae88  
07-02 18:25:00.973: I/DEBUG(35):     2afe6760 48804608 0000004a 00000000 00000000  
07-02 18:25:00.973: I/DEBUG(35):     2afe6770 00000000 00000000 ffffffff 00000004  
07-02 18:25:00.973: I/DEBUG(35):     2afe6780 2afe66e0 48277927 00000000 00000000  
07-02 18:25:00.973: I/DEBUG(35):     2afe6790 2ad03da8 00000040 0000003f 00000006  
07-02 18:25:00.973: I/DEBUG(35):     2afe67a0 00000000 00000001 2afe67b0 00000001  
07-02 18:25:00.973: I/DEBUG(35):     2afe67b0 4a95a9b8 4971db7c 4971db80 00000000  
07-02 18:25:00.973: I/DEBUG(35): memory near r7:
07-02 18:25:00.973: I/DEBUG(35):     50ea2cf0 33708101 00000014 f106fd26 656c6564  
07-02 18:25:00.983: I/DEBUG(35):     50ea2d00 65436574 2e836c6c 33708781 484ceaa1  
07-02 18:25:00.983: I/DEBUG(35):     50ea2d10 33708781 4835d6e3 33708781 4835ba55  
07-02 18:25:00.983: I/DEBUG(35):     50ea2d20 33708781 4835ba55 33708781 4835ba55  
07-02 18:25:00.983: I/DEBUG(35):     50ea2d30 33708081 0000007e 320e1f00 18306130  
07-02 18:25:00.983: I/DEBUG(35):     50ea2d40 10621102 20120d02 12150218 11021c40  
07-02 18:25:00.983: I/DEBUG(35):     50ea2d50 02203012 2440222d 50121d02 0d021021  
07-02 18:25:00.983: I/DEBUG(35):     50ea2d60 02182012 21501219 02050220 0130121a  
07-02 18:25:00.983: I/DEBUG(35):     50ea2d70 b40f0200 333f14bb 33708081 000000e6  
07-02 18:25:00.983: I/DEBUG(35):     50ea2d80 32061f00 021d0130 30000000 b03f18bb  
07-02 18:25:00.983: I/DEBUG(35):     50ea2d90 92f90208 123d02dc 9e012060 ffff4052  
07-02 18:25:00.983: I/DEBUG(35):     50ea2da0 203bd5ff 52a5013f 62fd0214 4442e501  
07-02 18:25:00.983: I/DEBUG(35):     50ea2db0 03024502 62f9017f a2150220 12210220  
07-02 18:25:00.983: I/DEBUG(35):     50ea2dc0 00000050 3f003b34 00000205 04bb2500  
07-02 18:25:00.994: I/DEBUG(35):     50ea2dd0 2901903f 50e2ea02 46021902 07005012  
07-02 18:25:00.994: I/DEBUG(35):     50ea2de0 306012ed 021d0228 01401222 02100200  
07-02 18:25:00.994: I/DEBUG(35): memory near r9:
07-02 18:25:00.994: I/DEBUG(35):     2e808070 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
07-02 18:25:00.994: I/DEBUG(35):     2e808080 337080c1 50e08089 00000000 00000006  
07-02 18:25:00.994: I/DEBUG(35):     2e808090 337080c1 50e08099 50e080b1 0000000a  
07-02 18:25:01.004: I/DEBUG(35):     2e8080a0 337080c1 50e080bd fffffffe 00000004  
07-02 18:25:01.004: I/DEBUG(35):     2e8080b0 337080c1 50e080cd 00000002 00000002  
07-02 18:25:01.004: I/DEBUG(35):     2e8080c0 337080c1 50e080dd 00000000 00000000  
07-02 18:25:01.004: I/DEBUG(35):     2e8080d0 337080c1 50e080f1 fffffffc 0000000c  
07-02 18:25:01.004: I/DEBUG(35):     2e8080e0 337080c1 50e08139 fffffff8 00000008  
07-02 18:25:01.004: I/DEBUG(35):     2e8080f0 337081c1 50e0bb3d 39519001 2e8096f5  
07-02 18:25:01.004: I/DEBUG(35):     2e808100 2721afc1 50e0b9fd 2e808091 3b22eda1  
07-02 18:25:01.004: I/DEBUG(35):     2e808110 2e808091 4be43821 2e808091 50e08081  
07-02 18:25:01.004: I/DEBUG(35):     2e808120 00000014 00000004 00000004 00000014  
07-02 18:25:01.013: I/DEBUG(35):     2e808130 00000000 00116052 00045876 00045804  
07-02 18:25:01.013: I/DEBUG(35):     2e808140 00014000 00000000 00000000 00000026  
07-02 18:25:01.013: I/DEBUG(35):     2e808150 00000000 33708941 00000012 00000000  
07-02 18:25:01.013: I/DEBUG(35):     2e808160 50e08081 33708241 0000000a 00000002  
07-02 18:25:01.013: I/DEBUG(35): memory near sl:
07-02 18:25:01.013: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d6c0 46304601 fa7af149 fc22f21d 46284604  
07-02 18:25:01.013: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d6d0 fae2f6c8 f6c29800 4620fc4a e8bdb004  
07-02 18:25:01.013: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d6e0 e92d81f0 460543f0 b0936800 38082400  
07-02 18:25:01.013: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d6f0 fd20f7f9 f7fd4606 f721ffd9 4621fd1e  
07-02 18:25:01.013: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d700 400bf88d 46284607 fb3ef7ff 020bf10d  
07-02 18:25:01.023: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d710 a8034601 f8fcf7f9 f8dd4620 9403800c  
07-02 18:25:01.023: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d720 f805f70a 300bf89d f21db11b 4605fbf1  
07-02 18:25:01.023: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d730 ac12e077 f04fa80d 93040901 3d24f844  
07-02 18:25:01.023: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d740 020cf104 902cf8cd f21e920a 68abf88d  
07-02 18:25:01.023: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d750 46494628 dd132b02 fb16f7ff f0014621  
07-02 18:25:01.023: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d760 b1f8f9d9 46282102 fb0ef7ff a8054601  
07-02 18:25:01.023: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d770 f8adf7fa a905a804 fe3af6c7 e00a9805  
07-02 18:25:01.023: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d780 fb02f7ff a8064601 f8a1f7fa a906a804  
07-02 18:25:01.023: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d790 fe2ef6c7 f6c29806 a80dfbea f886f21e  
07-02 18:25:01.034: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d7a0 b1184605 fbb4f21d e01b4605 9007a912  
07-02 18:25:01.034: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d7b0 a8074622 8d28f841 9001ab04 97004630  
07-02 18:25:01.034: I/DEBUG(35): memory near fp:
07-02 18:25:01.034: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d8d0 5603bb59 3379c381 2a119228 4a10a09c  
07-02 18:25:01.034: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d8e0 4a10a09c 3b282851 4a10a001 4971d8e4  
07-02 18:25:01.034: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d8f0 4971d910 3f885e38 560c9d25 50e1e105  
07-02 18:25:01.034: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d900 303b4ad1 3b282851 5602340d 5603bb59  
07-02 18:25:01.034: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d910 4971d930 3f896c84 50e1e105 303b4ad1  
07-02 18:25:01.034: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d920 3b282851 4d626ab5 56023455 5603bb59  
07-02 18:25:01.034: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d930 4971d94c 3f887360 3b282851 4d626ab5  
07-02 18:25:01.034: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d940 303b29f1 560233e9 303b3b5d 4971d964  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d950 5148dc38 303b0409 3b282851 3030a8e1  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d960 303267f9 4971d984 2722d674 303b0409  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d970 3b282851 3030a8e1 2722d5a1 0000000c  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d980 00000000 4971d9b0 27217768 00000000  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d990 27217681 00000000 00000000 00000000  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d9a0 00000002 00000000 00000002 00000002  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d9b0 ffffffff 9f1e1feb 41d4ed13 9f21531e  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d9c0 41d4ed13 00000000 00000000 00000000  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35): memory near ip:
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     48855064 4002e0a0 4002d0bc 4002d358 4002d81c  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     48855074 4002e484 4002da10 4002e7dc 4002e5dc  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     48855084 4002e888 40058ccb 4058fa9d 4059232d  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     48855094 4003817c 405bef71 408e86f4 405be9bd  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     488550a4 405be651 405be4d9 408e879c 408e87bc  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     488550b4 408e8898 40059fa0 4004148d 400452f1  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     488550c4 4003d825 400758f1 406ef779 405936c5  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     488550d4 40039880 4056b7d9 406eff81 406dc041  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     488550e4 406dc029 406f0359 406eff8d 406efa21  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     488550f4 406ef7e1 406f0a65 406ef9dd 4057dec5  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     48855104 40088550 40083e50 40086340 40086e74  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     48855114 40079e90 40080a28 400861e0 40083cf8  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     48855124 40086e88 400876c0 400758e7 400885e0  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     48855134 400899d0 40059240 40045141 40045681  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     48855144 4003e775 4003e85d 4003e8a9 4003ec6d  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     48855154 40032749 40037d34 40089a84 40089884  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35): memory near sp:
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d7e0 2a73c080 4971d898 2b077a58 2ae5c2e0  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d7f0 2afe66e0 4835b687 df0027ad 00000000  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d800 00000000 4971d898 2afe66e0 4835d6ff  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d810 4971d8e4 4971d8a4 4971d8e4 4971d8e0  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d820 4971d8a4 4971d8e4 4971d8e0 2a73c08c  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d830 00000000 4866acdb 4971d848 4971d8e0  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d840 2a118e68 00000003 4971d904 48587259  
07-02 18:25:01.044: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d850 2700dac1 2a118e10 4971d904 2a118e10  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d860 4835d6e3 00000000 50ea2d11 00000000  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d870 2e808091 485887a7 00000004 4971d904  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d880 4971d8f8 4866adb1 4971d8e0 2a118e10  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d890 2a73c07c 2a73d048 4971d8bc 4971d900  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d8a0 00000002 48853000 48846a10 2a118e10  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d8b0 00000000 33c181f1 560c9d25 2e808091  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d8c0 00000004 485886ad 4971d904 00000002  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4971d8d0 5603bb59 3379c381 2a119228 4a10a09c  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35): code around pc:
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4827f11c 3701ff28 d1a74547 f7a02000 e003f90e  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4827f12c 45536bf3 e7aad1f5 e8bdb013 b5708ff0  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4827f13c f8d04604 b97d52d8 f7a020f8 4621f8cd  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4827f14c f7f84606 f8d4ff9d f8c402d8 f7f962d8  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4827f15c 4628f98a f987f7f9 02d8f8d4 b538bd70  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4827f16c f8d04604 460d02f4 f001b108 682bfda0  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4827f17c f8d4b963 b14802f8 05896a41 f890d506  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4827f18c b91a276d f8d16801 479830f4 02f4f8d4  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4827f19c f002b108 f504fa11 f7fc608b 682bff42  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4827f1ac 02f4f8d4 602a2200 32f4f8c4 3004b110  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4827f1bc ffe7f7a6 0040f104 4038e8bd bbf3f7e7  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4827f1cc 47f0e92d 69834699 4605460c 4617b088  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4827f1dc 1a406ad9 eb464246 b1360600 02f4f8d5  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4827f1ec 6801b118 21006a8a f10d4790 46280a20  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4827f1fc 0800f04f 8d14f84a f7ff4651 4650ffb0  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4827f20c f812f7de 4622b1a6 a8044629 fa74f003  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35): code around lr:
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d6dc e8bdb004 e92d81f0 460543f0 b0936800  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d6ec 38082400 fd20f7f9 f7fd4606 f721ffd9  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d6fc 4621fd1e 400bf88d 46284607 fb3ef7ff  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d70c 020bf10d a8034601 f8fcf7f9 f8dd4620  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d71c 9403800c f805f70a 300bf89d f21db11b  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d72c 4605fbf1 ac12e077 f04fa80d 93040901  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d73c 3d24f844 020cf104 902cf8cd f21e920a  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d74c 68abf88d 46494628 dd132b02 fb16f7ff  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d75c f0014621 b1f8f9d9 46282102 fb0ef7ff  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d76c a8054601 f8adf7fa a905a804 fe3af6c7  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d77c e00a9805 fb02f7ff a8064601 f8a1f7fa  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d78c a906a804 fe2ef6c7 f6c29806 a80dfbea  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d79c f886f21e b1184605 fbb4f21d e01b4605  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d7ac 9007a912 a8074622 8d28f841 9001ab04  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d7bc 97004630 ff6af71a f7099808 4628ffb2  
07-02 18:25:01.054: I/DEBUG(35):     4835d7cc f2209e07 b910ff6b f7fe4630 f21dfa1a  
07-02 18:25:01.583: D/Zygote(38): Process 1147 terminated by signal (11)
07-02 18:25:01.593: I/ActivityManager(281): Process com.android.browser (pid 1147) has died.
```

Comment: I think this is just a 'regular' bug and not specific to the WebKit -> Chromium migration in Android 4.4. Also, you're confusing things: the 'Android Browser' app is _not_ Chromium. It's an app that uses the system WebView. If you run it on Android 4.3 you get the 4.3 WebView, if you run it on 4.4 you get the 4.4 WebView. If you want to use Chrome on Android 4.3 then install it from the Play store. Finally, without seeing a repro it's hard to suggest any workarounds.

Comment: I've got a similar crash but happens when injecting DOM elements into an `iframe` from JavaScript. So far no clue about the reason.

Comment: For what is worth, to workaround the issue, I've injected the HTML code using the `data:` schema in the URL ´src´ of the ´iframe´ (as mentioned in this other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6102829/2050333).