# Embed HTML with Style in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am returning a bunch of trusted html from a service and then in a `ng-repeat` I want to loop through the HTML and display it so I  am using `ng-bind-html="item.myHTML"` but if the HTML has `<style>` applied on it then this style is applied to the whole page, how can I have this style only be applied to the HTML that is in my `ng-bind-html`?

Here is what some of the HTML I get form my service might look like

```
<html>
<style>
body {
    background-color: linen;
}

h1 {
    color: maroon;
    margin-left: 40px;
} 
</style>
<p>test text</p>
<html>
```

But then all h1 tags on the page have color maroon, but I dont want that, just the embed html to have that style.

Thank you

Comment: If you are trying to apply styles to specific elements, using a `<style>` element would be an antipattern-- I'd recommend looking into [`ng-style`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle).

Comment: @anied The HTML comes with the style tag see example

Comment: Ugh.... that's not great-- is there any way you can have that style element be omitted from the returned HTML?  Seems like a real nightmare to deal with...

Comment: After seeing the sample, i think the word your looking for is <iframe> :) . Not a good solution but it might work...

Comment: @fluoresce yes I was thinking iframe also but I have html as a string how do I set that as the src of the iframe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6102829/1478876 ... but you should really try to do something like my answer bellow if you have any control over what the service provides... ng-repeating iframes is asking for a world of problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really.  style tags are global to the html document.  You will need to target your elements using standard css scoping rules.

If you have a unique attribute on each object in the list, such as an ID, and you are generating the content and the css, you could use the object ID as a html ID attribute for targeting your css.

```
<div id="object-001">
  <h1>Managing Director</h1>
  <span class="customer_name">Customer Name</span>
  <span class="customer_id">ID : 001</span>
  <p>This is the bio of the user<p>
</div>
<style>
#object-001 .customer_name { color : #f00; }
#object-001 .customer_id { color : #f00; }
#object-001 p {  color :purple; text-decoration: blink;  }  
#object-001 h1 { margin-left:40px; font-size:48px; }
div#object-001 { background-color : pink; font-face : "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif; }
</style>
```

ie. the string 'object-001' is dynamically generated for each record in your dataset.

Comment: Great idea, but the styles is not formatted enough where I can do that any other thoughts?

Comment: not sure exactly what your asking, i edited my example a bit.

Comment: So im not generating the code inside the style, so I cant preface them all with an #id

Comment: In that case, i can see two solutions.  1. iframes as above - this might work but note that having a lot of iframes on one page is bad for performance and rendering etc, has many problems and code will be copmplex.  2. Parse the content of the html snippets from the service, possibly using a documentFragment and jQuery and manipulate it into something like my example.  or 3. Talk to the people providing the service and suggest that they provide a more sane styling mechanism.

Comment: Valid, I wish I could talk to the people providing the service but this html is coming from email that are being parsed so I cant really control that lol, #2 might be an option

Comment: Use number 2 to remove the Style element altogether if possible, KISS paradigm...  it could get messy quick, otherwise.  If that's not possible and depending on how complicated the styling is, you might have no choice but iframe...  which is very powerful - but it does come with its headaches - open it in a window perhaps?!?!?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding a `scoped` attribute: `<style scoped></style>`

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_scoped.asp.

Depending on browser support needed.

Comment: scoped css is only implemented by firefox at this poiunt, and the feature has fallen out of the html specifications.

Comment: Scoped enjoys [almost no support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped).

Comment: Have a read of this...  [jQuery scoped CSS plugin](https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin).  Of course Jquery with AngularJS???  Plugin does fairly well...  check out the examples in different browsers.