# iframe not showing content in angular

Tags: angular, iframe

I have a component with an iframe like this:

```
<iframe [innerHTML]="html"></iframe>
```

if I do:

```
<div [innerHTML]="html"></div>
```

it works fine. But I need it to be an iframe for it has customs styles and scripts that must run outside the current page's context.

I've tryed using "DomSanitizer" with no effect

```
this.html = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(someHtmlStuff);
```

what could be the cause? The iframe ends up completelly empty and its html cannot be inspected in chrome's inspector

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102636/html-code-as-iframe-source-rather-than-a-url

Answer (score 0):

this fixed it:

--- TEMPLATE ---

```
 <iframe [src]="html"></iframe>
```

----- CODE -----

```
this.html = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,"+this.dialogRef.config.data.replace("\n",""));
```

the weird things to notice are

1. I had to remove line breaks
2. I had to concatenate this string "data:text/html;charset=utf-8,"