# (Confluence) Get an H1 element inside the body of an IFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, confluence

## Background

I am attempting to read (and eventually change) content within the `body` of an `IFrame` (in my example this involves `h1` tags) embedded in a [Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence) page.

### Confluence Behavior

Initially I didn't think it was significant, but as comments by @ScottMarcus illustrate; it *does* matter that this work is for a possible Confluence plugin. This is because I am using a [page decorator](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/using-standard-page-decorators/) containing JavaScript that executes when a user edits a Confluence page.

#### IFrame Restrictions

This means that (to my knowledge) I cannot have JavaScript execute *after* the editable `IFrame` has been added to the DOM. It also means that I cannot control what content is added to the `IFrame` (although this is OK/expected, as the idea is to enhance the user experience if they add tables and install the plugin).

#### Example

For reference, here is what the [wysiwyg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) Confluence editor looks like for my page (annotated with a couple key elements from my HTML below):

[image: Confluence Editable IFrame]

## Problem

Although I have been able to read/log the HTML present within the `IFrame`, I cannot seem to access elements in the same way I am able to within the main `document`. I have tried different variations on what I have below, doing things like...

- selecting elements by ID--for some reason this seems less reliable in this context?
- trying to get the `contents()` or `children()` of elements--in many cases I get null reference exceptions when trying this
- accessing the `body` from my `IFrame` object--again, this doesn't seem the same as doing `document.body`

### JavaScript

```js
function doStuff() {
    $('#wysiwygTextarea_ifr').ready(function () {
        let iFrame = document.getElementById('wysiwygTextarea_ifr');
        let frameDoc = iFrame.contentDocument ? iFrame.contentDocument : iFrame.contentWindow.document;
        let h1Tags = frameDoc.getElementsByTagName('h1');
        //would like to iterate over the collection of h1 tags here, but it always seems to be empty
    });
}
```

### HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="../Libraries/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    doStuff();
</script>

<iframe id="wysiwygTextarea_ifr">
  #document
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>blah</title>
    </head>

    <body id="tinymce">
        <h1 id="meh">abcde table</h1>
        <h1 id="neh">zzz</h1>
    </body>

    </html>
</iframe>

</html>
```

Comment: You are not using [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) correctly. You can't have any content within the opening and closing tags. You must use the `src` attribute to point to another resource.

Comment: Also you can use `this` inside `ready()` instead of refetching the `iframe`.

Comment: And, your `script` elements should be located just before the closing `body` tag so that by the time you run them, all the HTML will have been parsed. Right now, your code executes before the `iframe` has even been reached.

Comment: Either use jQuery consistently or not at all.

Comment: @ScottMarcus hah, good to know but I'm not sure I have a say in that (I tried to mimic the Confluence HTML that renders alongside my own the best I could). Where would be the best place to apply the `src` attribute (assuming I have access to that code). Thanks!

Comment: `src` gets added directly to the `iframe` opening tag.

Comment: @Lain so if I replace `let iFrame = document.getElementById('wysiwygTextarea_ifr');` with `let iFrame = this` I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined` when the next line executes. Is there an alternate way to get the 'document' inside the frame in this case? Thanks!

Comment: @ScottMarcus You make a good point about script location. But I think the same issue applies because I'm using a 'decorator' page in Confluence which is injected each time a page loads (in other words--I don't think I can control where the IFrame goes). That said, I did try moving the script blocks lower in my code and I get the same result. Thanks.

Comment: @JavaScript lol that's fair. This is what I get for spending hours combing vanilla JavaScript and jQuery solutions :p

Comment: What do you get by logging `frameDoc.body.innerHTML`?

Comment: @Lain `console.log(frameDoc.body.innerHTML);` appears to give me an empty string (or at least, the result is not undefined).

Comment: The way you predefine markup inside the iframe does not work. [Check this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102636/html-code-as-iframe-source-rather-than-a-url)

Comment: @Lain Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't believe I would have the ability to edit the `IFrame` rendered by Confluence. The HTML in my example is essentially a slimmed down version of what ultimately renders what is present in the screenshot I added. In other words, the *user* determines the contents of the IFrame via the wysiwyg GUI. So I am merely trying to "listen" for (and ultimately mutate) certain content (e.g. - `h1` and `table` elements).