# payment gateway integration modal doesn't show up after loading content in iframe

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express, vuejs2

I'm trying to add payment gateway into my website and I created a route which sends html content after the purchase is done. I tried to show the html content in my website using iframe but all I see is a blank document. However there is another website that is using the same payment gateway and they get a modal which shows a qr code. I want similar thing on my website. What am I doing wrong in my code?

This is the [reference site](https://dalinstores.com/game/mobile-legend):

Use this id: 720390172 and zone id: 10328 and select any item option then select abapay and submit, then a modal appears with a qr code

[payment documentation site](https://www.payway.com.kh/developers/create-transaction/)

Backend code

```
export const createSingleOrder = async (req, res) => {
  const item = req.body;

  try {
      const paywayResponse = await initiatePaywayPayment(item);
        if (paywayResponse.status !== 'success') {
            throw new Error('Payment with PayWay failed');
        }
      res.json({ status: 'success', htmlContent: paywayResponse.htmlContent });
  } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
};

async function initiatePaywayPayment(item) {
  const paywayApiUrl = process.env.PAYWAY_API_URL;
  const merchantId = process.env.PAYWAY_MERCHANT_ID;
  const publicKey = process.env.PAYWAY_PUBLIC_KEY;
  
  const reqTime = new Date().toISOString();
  const tranId = generateTranId();
  const amount = item.price;
  const paymentOption = 'abapay'; 

  const hashString = `${merchantId}${tranId}${amount}${reqTime}${publicKey}`;
  const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha512', publicKey)
                  .update(hashString)
                  .digest('base64');
  const form = new FormData();
  form.append('merchant_id', merchantId);
  form.append('tran_id', tranId);
  form.append('req_time', reqTime);
  form.append('amount', amount);
  form.append('payment_option', paymentOption);
  form.append('hash', hash);
  try {
      const response = await axios.post(paywayApiUrl, form, {
          headers: form.getHeaders(),
      });
          console.log('response', response.data)
          return { status: 'success', htmlContent: response.data };

  } catch (error) {
      return { status: 'error', message: error.message };
  }
}
```

In the frontend I'm using vue2

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="app">
    <div v-if="paymentHtmlContent" class="payment-iframe-container">
      <iframe id="paymentIframe" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <b-button
      @click="buyNowSingle"
      >Buy Now</b-button
    >
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 data() {
    return {
      paymentHtmlContent: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
     loadPaymentIframe() {
      const iframe = document.getElementById("paymentIframe");
      if (iframe && this.paymentHtmlContent) {
        iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
        iframe.contentWindow.document.write(this.paymentHtmlContent);
        iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
      }
    },
    buyNowSingle() {
        const newItem = {
          price: this.selectedDiamond.price,
        };
        axios
          .post(
            `${process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT}/transact/createsingleorder`,
            {
              items: newItem,
            }
          )
          .then((response) => {
            if (response.data && response.data.htmlContent) {
            this.paymentHtmlContent = response.data.htmlContent;
            this.$nextTick(() => {
               this.loadPaymentIframe();
            });
          }
           
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Purchase failed:", error);
          });
       } 
      }
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6102829/22591334) help you?