# How can I create jquery previous and next buttons that go through URLs in an array (pagination)

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I have an array of URLs, say

```
pageList = ["index.html", "01.html", "02.html"]
```

and I want to create a function in which .prev and .next go to the previous/next item in that array, so if I'm in index.html, clicking next will go to "01.html", and if i'm in "01.html" it'll go to "02.html" and so on.

How could I do that? I have found many "pagination" jquery plugins, but they all seem to paginate through divs in the same URL, but I need something that actually goes to another page, something like

```
window.location = currentLocation + 1
```

Sorry for the noob question, it really comes from a noob.
Ta!

Comment: you want to navigate to some other page or same page with different url?

Comment: same page different url? from me.com/01.html to me.com/02.html

Comment: check links :
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html
https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/htaccess_redirect
http://www.webconfs.com/url-rewriting-tool.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it that way:

```
var pageList = ["index.html", "01.html", "02.html"];
var url = window.location.pathname; // e.g. http://me.com/index.html
var page = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1); // e.g. index.html
var currentPosition = pageList.indexOf(page); // e.g. 0, 1 or 2

document.getElementById('next-btn').onclick = function(){
    // if the URL is not in the list, do nothing
    if(currentPosition==-1) return;
    // if we're at the end, go back to index, else, go to next page
    window.location = currentPosition<pageList.length-1? pageList[++currentPosition]:pageList[0];
}
```

Insert that script on every page and it should work if you have an element with the ID `next-btn` to click on.

If you are not familiar with the last line's syntax, it could also be written that way:

```
if(currentPosition<pageList.length-1) {window.location = pageList[++currentPosition];}
else {window.location = pageList[0];}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure pageList array is in the global scope. Or you can pass it as the second parameter. Depending on where that array is stored. Set next to true if it's next, set it to false if it's prev.

```
var pageList = ["index.html", "01.html", "02.html"];

function getUrl(next) { //next = true or false
    current = window.location;
    index = (next) ? 1 : -1;
    for(i = 0;i < pageList.length;i++) {
        if(current.toString().indexOf(pageList[i]) > -1) {
            return (pageList[i + index]);
        }
    }
}

var nextUrl = getUrl(true);
var prevUrl = getUrl(false);
```

Comment: I am using this function and work fine. Is there a way to edit the function when I get to the end of the array to start from the beginning again?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an IFrame and have your Next Prev buttons functions set the source of the IFrame from your Array.

Comment: An example of the implementation is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000987/dynamically-set-iframe-src