# Update iframe src attribute dynamically with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to update an iframe on a page using JavaScript, but it's not working. This example seems pretty straightforward, but the page is not loading the iframe with the new page once I click the button. I'm doing this all locally.

```
<html>
    <body>
    <script>
    function changeIframeSrc() {
        document.getElementById('myFrame').src = "test2.html";
    }
    </script>
    <form>
    <button onclick="changeIframeSrc()">Click here</button>
    <iframe id="myFrame" src="test1.html"></iframe>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000987/dynamically-set-iframe-src

Comment: Are there any console errors? Does the page exist and correct path etc?

Comment: That duplicate doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove The form tags

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function changeIframeSrc() {
    document.getElementById('myFrame').src = "test2.html";
}
</script>
<button onclick="changeIframeSrc()">Click here</button>
<iframe id="myFrame" src="test1.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That did the trick...wow thanks. Do you know why the form tags screwed it up?

Answer (score 2):

The script *does* load the new `<iframe>`. The problem is that the `<form>` is *also* submitted (if the browser supports implicit form submission) which then reloads the page with the original `<iframe>`.

One simple solution is to remove the `<form>` element. Without a `<form>` element, there can be no form submission:

```
<!--form-->
 <button onclick="changeIframeSrc()">Click here</button>
 <iframe id="myFrame" src="test1.html"></iframe>
<!--/form-->
```

Another is to prevent the default action of the `<button>` by returning `false` from the `onclick` handler:

```
<form>
 <button onclick="changeIframeSrc(); return false;">Click here</button>
 <iframe id="myFrame" src="test1.html"></iframe>
</form>
```

However, there is a problem with these solutions. If the browser doesn't execute the script, or the script fails in some unanticipated way, the user is left with a dead button. Ideally, the button should submit the form in a useful way when the script doesn't run. Eg.:

```
<form>
 <button name=frame value=2 onclick="changeIframeSrc(); return false;">Click here</button>
 <iframe id="myFrame" src="test1.html"></iframe>
</form>
```

The add some server-side code that outputs the form, but with `src="test2.html"` as the default `<iframe>` source if the page is requested with the form data `frame=2`.